# Cambiar el estilo de mapa usando MapBox en Android

Tags: android, mapbox

Tengo un mapa cargado con Mapbox pero no encuentro la manera de cambiar el estilo por defecto trae un street map, aqui esta en codigo xml de la vista:

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="40.73581"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-73.99155"
    mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="11" />
```

Creería que es styleUrl pero no encuentro en la documentación para cambiarlo tipo satélite por ejemplo

Comment: debes definir una url del estilo, entra a la página https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles , agrego un pequeño tutorial de como cambiar el estilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes definir el estilo en la propiedad [mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-style-url/), pero el valor debe ser una url :

```
mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="https://..."
```

en el ejemplo que muestra tu pregunta estas realizando la definición como se realiza en web ( `"mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10"` ), lo cual es incorrecto en Android.

en la [pagina de estilos](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles) puedes obtener la url del estilo que deseas definir.

Debes entrar a la página https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles y registrarte, ahí puedes usar un template o subir un estilo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí selecciona la url del estilo deseado, en este caso "Satellite":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes agregar este valor en tu archivo `strings.xml`

```
<string name="style_satelite">https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/jorgesys/cjoj4c2g1310u2rntda2bk8f7.html?fresh=true&title=true&access_token=pk.abJ1Ijoiam9yZ2VzeXMiLCJhIjoiY2pvajQ4bW9kMDB</string>
```

y llamarlo en tu vista:

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="40.73581"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-73.99155"
    mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="@strings/style_satelite"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="11" />
```